# How can I get my mongoose collection data displayed on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fetch

I am trying to fetch the data from my mongoose collection, and dispaly that data on client side. But I am getting 'Object' on the cilent side instead of data, but the data is saved in the database.

Can anyone help me, Thanks

This is my code

router.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Library', { useNewUrlParser: true });


const api_list = new mongoose.Schema({
    data:Array
});

const api = mongoose.model('api_listLs', api_list);

router.post('/api/list/Post', (request, response) => {
        const data = request.body
        const apiList = new api({data:data});
        apiList.save().then(() => {
            console.log(data)
            response.json(data);
        }).catch(() => {
            response.status(400).send("Item was not send to the database")
        });
});



router.get('/api/list/Get', (request, response) => {
    api.find({},(err,data)=> {
        if(err){
            response.end();
            return;
        }
        response.json(data);
    });
});
```

page1.js

I used a fetch 'POST' method to pass data into database. And save it in a collection

```
function TableRow() {
    let items = 'hey'
    let domore = 'hi'
    let cells = document.querySelectorAll('#recieve-info td');
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.onclick = async function () {
        let prevcell = cell.previousElementSibling;
        if (prevcell) {
            let data = {items, domore}
            let options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            };
            
            const response = await fetch('/api/list', options);
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
}
```

page2.js

Here I used fetch 'GET' method to to retreive data from database and show it on client side

```
async function ParaG() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/list');
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  alert(data);

  for (item of data) {
    const para = document.querySelector('.Second-Para');
    para.innerHTML += `${item.data}, ${item.data}`
  }
  
}
```

'.Second-Para'  is a p element in a container 'div'

Here is the output. I am getting 'Object' instead of data
[image: I am getting 'object' not the value]

This app pass data from one page to another by onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result is in data key and data is array of objects so use `{data}` to access the data like this:

```
async function ParaG() {
  const response = await fetch('/api/list');
  const {data} = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  alert(data);

  for (item of data) {
    let info = item.data[0];//access to data 
    const para = document.querySelector('.Second-Para');
    para.innerHTML += `${info.items}, ${info.domore}`
  }
  
}
```

Comment: after using response.json({data})  now i am getting 'data is not iterable'

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i am still getting `Object `

Comment: whats the result of console.log() in ParaG(), with my answer

Comment: I am getting an array holding the data in object      ` (2) [{…}, {…}]`      i have saved data two times ` 0: {data: Array(1), _id: "600ae1bbee333b422c5425dc", __v: 0} ` 
`1: {data: Array(1), _id: "600ae6274f3b200420b0884d", __v: 0}`    This is what i am getting in console

Comment: you should access to `data:array` with length 1, I updated my answer